# Riverpod - How to access a provider in a test?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, riverpod

I have this snippet:

```dart
final countProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) {
  return 0;
});

class CountWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CountWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final count = ref.watch(countProvider);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(count.toString()),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            ref.read(countProvider.notifier).state++;
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is a pretty simplified code, but the idea is that it is using a state provider.

I would like to write a test and verify that, after some actions, the provider is in a specific state (without relying on the UI, here I could use `find.text()`, but my state could be much more complex).

I would like to access the model in my test after pumping my widget:

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(const CountWidget());

await tester.tap();
await tester.pump();

// ... Some other actions.

final currentCountState = // ?
expect(currentCountState, 3); // For example.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution 1

[`ProviderScope`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/ProviderScope-class.html) has a static method [`.containerOf`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/ProviderScope/containerOf.html) which returns the `ProviderContainer` of the closer `ProviderScope` of the current `context`.

Let's say you want to get the `WidgetRef ref` associated/active for the widget with a key `Key('key')`, you can obtain its `context` with [`tester.element`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetController/element.html). Then you can use `ProviderScope.containerOf`:

```dart
final context = tester.element(find.byType(Key('key')));
final providerContainter = ProviderScope.containerOf(context); // <- Your `ref`.
```

---

### Solution 2

Here, `CountWidget` extends `ConsumerWidget` which extends `ConsumerStatefulWidget` which extends `StatefulWidget`.

In riverpod's code, we can see that the created state is actually a `_ConsumerState`:

```dart
class _ConsumerState extends ConsumerState<ConsumerWidget> {
  @override
  WidgetRef get ref => context as WidgetRef;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.build(context, ref);
  }
}
```

`context` and `ref` are actually the same object.

And this is because in `ConsumerStatefulWidget`:

```dart
/// A [StatefulWidget] that can read providers.
abstract class ConsumerStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  /// A [StatefulWidget] that can read providers.
  const ConsumerStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
  ConsumerState createState();

  @override
  ConsumerStatefulElement createElement() {
    return ConsumerStatefulElement(this);
  }
}
```

The associated element (which is the what is used for the `context` is a `ConsumerStatefulElement`:

```dart
class ConsumerStatefulElement extends StatefulElement implements WidgetRef {
  // ...
}
```

So in the test, you can use `tester.element` to get `ref`:

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(const CountWidget());

await tester.tap();
await tester.pump();

// ... Some other actions.

final ref = tester.element<ConsumerStatefulElement>(find.byType(CountWidget));
final currentCountState = ref.read(countProvider);
expect(currentCountState, 3); // For example.
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is a litte bit hacky and will throw an error if the provider is read when it is already disposed. The correct way is to explicitly use `ProviderContainer` and `UncontrollerProviderScope` in test. By using this we can use the provider outside of a widget as well.

```dart
// make sure riverpod is imported
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

test('outside of widget', () {
   final container = ProviderContainer(
     overrides: [
       // define your overrides here if required
     ]
   );

   final count = container.read(countProvider);
   expect(count, 0);
});

testWidgets('Test the widget', () async {
   final container = ProviderContainer();

   await tester.pumpWidget(
      UncontrolledProviderScope(
        container: container,
        child: const CountWidget(),
      )
   );

   await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
   final currentCount = container.read(countProvider);
   expect(currentCount, 1);
});
```

References:

- [ProviderContainer](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/ProviderContainer-class.html)
- [UncontrollerProviderScope](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/UncontrolledProviderScope-class.html)

Comment: The issue with that is that if your pumped widget introduces a `ProviderScope` with an override in the widget tree, you won't be able to access the provider with your method

Comment: @ValentinVignal  True that.  I just put the `overrides` just for the sake of completeness. It's not necessary to override unless you needed to. Like from your given example, it doesn't need an override.

Comment: It is actually pretty common to override when you want to scope your models. You can look at the [riverpod examples](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/tree/master/examples/marvel)

Comment: Sure, if you are talking about using it to scope models in you view. Heck, I override a lot instead of mocking in test as well.